# Does List.retainAll() use HashMap internally?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, overriding

I am purposefully violating the hashCode contract that says that if we override `equals()` in our class, we must override `hashCode()` as well, and I am making sure that no Hash related data structures (like **HashMap**, **HashSet**, etc) are using it. The problem is that I fear methods like `removeAll()` and `containsAll()` of Lists might use HashMaps internally, and in that case, since I am not overriding `hashCode()` in my classes, their functionality might break.

Can anyone please conform whether my doubt is valid ? The classes contain a lot of fields that are being used for equality comparison, and I will have to come up with an efficient technique to get a hashCode using all of them. I really don't require them in any hash-related operations, and as such, I am trying to avoid implementing `hashCode()`

Comment: Which implementation of the `List` interface?

Comment: You could: 1. Look at the source code 2. Test it

Comment: You can lookup the source code of for example `ArrayList` in the `src.zip` that's in your JDK installation directory. But really, why are you "purposefully violating the hashCode contract"? Sounds like a recipe for disaster. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: +1 look at the source code, exactly

Comment: Even if the current implementation of the List variant you use works for you, it may change in the next release, triggering a hard to find bug. And even if you consistently do not use hash data structures, there is no guarantee that new members of your project team (possibly after you have left) won't ever do it, again triggering a hard to find bug.

Comment: A surprising number, yes. Honestly, the question should really be downvoted for total lack of research.

Comment: But, as others have pointed out, the question is unanswerable in its current form (e.g. which `List` implementation?) and even if it holds right now, it won't necessarily hold in future if one has deliberately broken the contract. They're called contracts for a reason, after all.

Comment: Don't. Whatever you're doing, this is the wrong way to go about it. Step away from the keyboard and think about the problem some more.

Comment: @Gabe: +1...  Exactly.  It's a bit easy to answer the question when one does know the answer and say *"Use the source, Luke"* when one doesn't know the answer.  For example should have this question been: *"Do I need a proper hashCode() implementation if I put elements in an HashMap?"* I'm willing to be a *lot* of money that the answer would not have been *"look at the source code / test it"*.

Comment: Moreover this "answer" isn't an answer: as *Péter Török* noted, even if things do work with the current implementation of the List variant OP is using, it may break in the next release.  So *"Test it"* is hardly a sound advice.  If you believe this answer should be closed, vote for close instead of trying to gain rep...

Comment: Its an ArrayList implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple way to test if hashCode() is being used anywhere is to override hashCode() for your class, make it print a statement to the console (or a file if you prefer) and then return some random value (won't matter since you said you don't want to use any hash-based classes anyway).

However, i think the best would be to just override it, i'm sure some IDE's even can do it for you (Eclipse can, for example). If you never expect it to get called, it can't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for the eclipse tip.. that was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

From AbstractCollection.retainAll()

```
 * <p>This implementation iterates over this collection, checking each
 * element returned by the iterator in turn to see if it's contained
 * in the specified collection.  If it's not so contained, it's removed
 * from this collection with the iterator's <tt>remove</tt> method.

public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
boolean modified = false;
Iterator<E> e = iterator();
while (e.hasNext()) {
    if (!c.contains(e.next())) {
    e.remove();
    modified = true;
    }
}
return modified;
}
```

Comment: I checked the contains() method too.. it doesn't actually use any hash-related functions.. but it might change in the future.. so the best way would be to implement a hashCode() implementation, I guess.

Comment: If you do `list.retainAll(hashSet)`, defining a hashCode/equals would be used.  If you do `list.retainAll(list)`, only equals will be used.  You can always do `list.retainAll(new HashSet(collection))` to ensure a hash lookup is used.

Answer (score 2):

As for

> I will have to come up with an efficient technique to get a hashCode using all of them

You don't need to use all of the fields used by `equals` in your `hashCode` implementation:

> It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the  two objects must produce distinct integer results.  However, the  programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Therefore, your hashCode implementation could be very simple and still obey the contract:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return 1;
}
```

This will ensure that hash-based data structures still work (alebit at degraded performance). If you add logging to your hashCode implementation, then you could even check if it is ever called.